# Using Apache commons get all files with specific name searching recursively inside a given root directory and apply directory filter

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I have users.xml files in an example directory structure like below, I like to make use of Apache commons FileUtils.listFiles to get the list of users.xml along with absolute path while applying filters to search within folders called users and applying file filter to get the only users.xml.

[image]

I tried the following java code but it does not list anything.

String filePath = "C:\Test\";

```
    File root = new File(filePath);

    IOFileFilter fileFilter = FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("users.xml");

    IOFileFilter dirFilter = FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("users");


    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, fileFilter, dirFilter);

    System.out.println("No of files : " + files.size());

    for (File file: files) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: You don't need any third party library, simply traverse the directory recursively and find the file.

Comment: Yes I can. But like I mentioned in my question I am specifically trying to achieve this using Apache FileUtils.listFiles and then applying filters.

Comment: @NageshNagaraja Does it work when you use `TrueFileFilter.TRUE` as the directory filter?

Comment: Thank you. It worked with that. However is there a filter to look only inside specific subdirectory name. For example it should look for users.xml only inside a sub directory called users and ignore users.xml existing under any other folder.